# Windows 7 clipboard has a graphic on it by default

Tags: windows-7, clipboard

I have a Samsung mini laptop with Windows 7 Home premium installed.  Any time I start a program that can access the clipboard, I find that a graphic is already on it (without me adding it).  I have deleted every entry on the clipboard, but sure enough, the graphic is back the next time I start a progran.   The applications I am using are Microsoft Office 2010 applications.  I have even taken the drastic step of restoring my system to "first time user" statis and reinstalled all software.  This does not happen on my other Windows 7 PCs.  Any ideas to try to correct this?
James asked what the graphic is.  It appears to be a black/white Bluetooth sign.  I say this because occaisionally, I will have a colored one of those appear as well.

Comment: @Huskehn yes, the question was edited in response to that comment.

Comment: Doug, you may want to *register* your account, otherwise you won't be able to make edits to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Some application is copy/pasting that graphic, probably onto a toolbar. Look for add-ins for your browser, Word, etc. That is the most likely culprit.